# Bootstrap 4's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to integrate Bootstrap 4 in my website but I get the error of `jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.` I tried to use a different version of jQuery but it's still not working. When I try to remove `bootstrap4.js` the error doesn't show up so it means the file path is working and don't have a problem with it. So what's the problem here?

File Directory

- centralizedcalapan

  - admin

    - controller
    - model
    - view

      - include
      - index.php
  - resources

    - css
    - js

      - jquery-3.2.1.min.js

[image: Screenshot of the error, "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript."]

css

```
  <link href="../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

js

```
  <script src="../../resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try jQuery in head Section and bootstrap js at last just before `</body>`,
Or try both in head section but make sure you first include jQueryJS and then bootstarpJS file

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="../../resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

that is the line you type. but, you are showing in your directory path `jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

so. you'd type `<script src="../../resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
"></script>`

Comment: Oh my mistake but even still its not working. The `jquery.min.js` this is the different version i tried i copy the last code.

Comment: but, you have `jquery.min.js` in your source path??

Comment: I think. it would be helpful if you show your real source path directory

Comment: As i said. I tried many different version right? The `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` is my main `jquery` when it didnt work i tried downloading another version which is `jquery.min.js` and when im typing to post this thread i forgot to change the code. You got me sir?

Comment: well. another solution could be use the `Content Delivery Network`, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js`

Comment: but. it's rare. how have you downloaded the dependencies?? `NPM`, `Bower`, `yaml`??

Comment: I download whole file. I tried the cdn of jquery still not working. :3

Answer (score 0):

Just look on this example:
if you have such tree directory witch looks like as yours:

```
public 
    style
        bootstrap.min.css
    scripts
        bootstrap.min.js
        jquery-3.2.1.min.js
views 
  component 
      head
```

so in your **head**  file you should include those links and JS on this way

```
<head>
...
    <!--links-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--scripts-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
It works for me perfectly.Hope it will for you.
```

> Just that i want put your intention to something : somtimes the
>   browser use the files contained on the cache so one u update it still
>   using **old file**.To fix this problem just click on **ctrl+h** and
>   then and then select delete browser data and then select  delete
>   **cached images and files** and validate.
>
> Like this it gonna concider the changement your browser. and also
>   always update with **ctrl+f5.**

Comment: If you want i will send you my jquery-3.2.1.min.js it may work for you if your problem is that.

Comment: can you send me?

Comment: give your mail adress and just tell me if it's the complete tree. Try to use absolute path like this :C:/wamp/www/Mini_Prj/public/scripts in my case maybe the problem is on the given path

Comment: where do you call those link i mean is that on your index file

Comment: try this  <script src="../resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> for all of them besides puting ../../ put only ../ try it and update me. You have the same tree as me it should work

Comment: And put your includes on the head like i show in the example.Try if that will work for you